# What is the best way to clean a roasting tray/baking tray that has sauce burned on to it?

Tags: equipment, cleaning, roasting

I made [this recipe](http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/3207/sticky-chinese-wings-and-cucumber) last week - chicken wings roasted in a marinade of soy sauce, brown sugar and white wine vinegar. It was delicious but lots of the marinade has burned onto my baking tray, and I'm struggling to get it clean.

I put it in to soak immediately, scrubbed and then tried washing powder, but it is still very firmly stuck on. Does anyone have any cleaning ideas that might help me in this case?

Comment: What is the pan made of? It makes a huge difference to cleaning methods.

Comment: When you say washing powder, are you talking about supermarket stuff like Ajax or a specialty product like Barkeeper's Friend?

Comment: @Aaronut, I actually thought "washing powder" = laundry detergent, so I was mightily confused. Thanks for the alternate interpretation. :-)

Comment: No - I think you may have had it right Marti - I mean powder we put in our washing machine to clean clothes.

Comment: I have no idea what Ajax or Barkeeper's Friend are I'm afraid!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Half fill it with water, then put in on the stove top over a medium heat.  Work the burnt-on bits with a wooden spoon or spatula as the water starts to boil.  You should be able to soften it up and be able to get it off then.

Comment: I do this with vinegar instead, just a little bit and it pulls everything up.

Comment: @Bluebelle, great! did you go for just water or vinegar too?

Answer (score 2):

Ammonia does a really nice job on pans with a lot of burn on black debris that won't come off with scrubbing.

- Remove the bulk of the debris on the
  pan,(you're already there)
- Then place the pan, and a container
  with some 1/2c(120ml) of household
  ammonia in a plastic bag.
- Close up the bag (doesn't have to be totally air
  tight).
- Leave it sit for several hours to
  a couple days.The burned
  on stuff will come off pretty easily.
- Then wash the pan normally.

I strongly advocate letting the pan/bag combination sit outside or in a garage or very well ventilated room during the soaking phase.

This works great on broiler pans, but I have used it on other pans as well.

**Do NOT use** this technique on aluminum pans.

Comment: what happens if you use the technique on aluminum pans?

Comment: And what happens on copper pans?

Answer (score 2):

There is a special tool that I use for tough pot cleaning jobs. It is a small hard nylon square, with three curved corners and one more pointed corner.  The edges are slightly beveled.  I have several that came with my order of pampered chef bakeware. I think you might be able to buy them retail or online also.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much to say about this: The only thing you can try is to use fat-resolving detergents. The rest that is really burnt to coal has to be removed physically by hand. No way around this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to **clean a roasting tray** with some icky sticky **grease** solidified on it that simply wouldn't come off.

I put it **under the grill** for 10-15mins at 220degC, then took it out and placed it in my steel sink then (carefully and with one hand in an oven glove!) I put a small amount of washing up liquid on and **scrubbed it with a steel wire scourer**.

The grease, which now seemed to have been burnt by the heat came off very quickly.

Obviously this comes under the "don't try this at home kids" but I didn't need any potent cleaning products.

Answer (score 0):

Baking Soda and vinegar made to a paste, use paste to buff pot or pan with a soft cloth. Works like magic.

Comment: Works like water, which is exactly what you get when you mix those two. Separately, they work OK as cleaners; together, they make water. I guess if it's still pasty then you've got a little extra baking soda, which is equivalent to just a baking soda paste - the vinegar has been entirely neutralized before it hits the tray.