# Can I get a haze off of ceramic cooking pans

Tags: equipment

I have 2 baking pans that are clean but have a haze on the bottom and sides. these are Rival roaster ovens and I think they are ceramic inserts. Can I get this haze off?

Comment: Here is a related answer that may be helpful: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8968/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-a-roasting-tray-baking-tray-that-has-sauce-burned

Answer (score 2):

Two opposite things to try, depending on what the haze is (or what works.)

1. Barkeepers Friend (mostly oxalic acid) or vinegar (acetic acid, not
   quite as strong as oxalic.)
2. Baking soda and water paste (alkaline) or soak in hot water with
   baking soda.
3. Actually, that brings a third to mind - mechanical - Bon-Ami -
   feldspar - abrasive but softer than glass (which is what ceramic
   glaze is, more or less.)

Default assumption would be that it's a hard water deposit, so start with the acid approach, but all three gives you options if that doesn't work.

Another mostly-mechanical option that won't require shopping for a special cleaning product - try scrubbing with toothpaste.